# Integration related to exponential random variable

Tags: calculus, probability

Given $\lambda,T>0$, consider the following integral.

\begin{align}
X&=\int_0^T t\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\mathrm d t= \left[ -t e^{-\lambda t}
  \right]\Big|_0^T +\int_0^T e^{-\lambda t} \mathrm d t
  \\&=-T e^{-\lambda T}+\left[ \frac{1}{-\lambda}e^{-\lambda t}
  \right]\Big|_0^{T}=\frac{1}{\lambda}-\left( T+\frac{1}{\lambda}
  \right)e^{-\lambda T}
\end{align}

Am I performing the ***integral by parts*** right????

I don't think so but don't know which parts go wrong.

In particular, I think $X>0$ , but when I try to solve the equation $X=0$ it gives me:

\begin{align}
 &\frac{1}{\lambda}-\left( T+\frac{1}{\lambda}
  \right)e^{-\lambda T}=0
  \\ \longrightarrow & e^{-\lambda
  T}=\frac{\frac{1}{\lambda}}{T+\frac{1}{\lambda}}=\frac{1}{1+\lambda T}<1
\end{align} Since $f(t)=e^{-\lambda t}$ is a decreasing function
respective to $t$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(\infty)=0$, there is an
$T_0>0$ such that $f(T_0)=\frac{1}{1+\lambda T_0}$, this seems  to contradict to the fact that $X>0$. um............Any idea?

Comment: The integral by parts is correct. So, if I understand correctly, are you trying to express T as a function of X?

Comment: I am trying to reach some contradiction but my reasoning is wrong:)

Comment: I don't understand the kind of contradiction you're looking for. The integrand is a positively defined function and the integral must therefore be not negative. If $T=0$ then $X=0$ and vice-versa. If $X>0$, then there is only one solution for $T$ such that $T>0$.

Comment: I try to examine the statement when $T>0$ we should have $X>0$, but I find a $T_0>0$ such that $X=0$ to reach a contradiction. But my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: If $T>0$ then $X>0$. Guaranteed for all $T>0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I do not have sufficient reputation points to post a comment.

The only solution is $T_0 = 0$. You are solving for $T$ such that
$$
  (1+ \lambda T)e^{-\lambda T} = 1.
$$

Note that $1 + \lambda T \leq e^{\lambda T}$ with equality if and only if $T=0$. So, for $T > 0$,
$$
   (1+ \lambda T)e^{-\lambda T} < e^{\lambda T}e^{-\lambda T} = 1
$$
Therefore, the only solution is $T=0$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right:) my stupid.........